# How to checkout a specific Subversion revision from the command line?

Tags: windows, svn, command-line, tortoisesvn

I want to checkout a specific revision of a folder in [Subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) using the command line.

I don't see an option for specifying the revision number in `TortoiseProc.exe`,

```
TortoiseProc.exe /command:checkout <url>
```

How do I get the revision I want? Is `TortoiseProc.exe` the right tool for what I want to do?

Answer (score 497):

If you already have it checked out locally then you can `cd` to where it is checked out, then use this syntax:

```bash
$ svn up -rXXXX
```

ref: [Checkout a specific revision from subversion from command line](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html)

Comment: For some reason this does nothing for me.  Still at the old revision.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Have you locally modified the file you're trying to update?

Comment: How do you do hard reset? (Ignoring conflicts?)

Comment: @DilipRajBaral `svn revert` on a specific file, or `svn revert --depth infinity` to reset recursively

Comment: How do I confirm that this command was successful? `svn info --show-item revision` shows a different number than the one I entered.

Answer (score 341):

Either

```
svn checkout url://repository/path@1234
```

or

```
svn checkout -r 1234 url://repository/path
```

Comment: I had to remove space after -r so "-r1234" worked for me.

Answer (score 262):

Any reason for using TortoiseProc instead of just the normal svn command line?

I'd use:

```
svn checkout svn://somepath@1234 working-directory
```

(to get revision 1234)

Comment: Reason: Windows

Answer (score 42):

You should never use TortoiseProc.exe as a command-line Subversion client! TortoiseProc should be utilized only for automating TortoiseSVN's GUI. See the  [note in TortoiseSVN's Manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html):

> Remember that TortoiseSVN is a GUI client, and this automation guide
>   shows you how to make the TortoiseSVN dialogs appear to collect user
>   input. If you want to write a script which requires no input, you
>   should use the official Subversion command line client instead.

Use the Subversion [command-line svn.exe client](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/). With the command-line client, you can

- checkout a working copy in REV revision:

  1. [`svn checkout --revision REV https://svn.example.com/svn/MyRepo/trunk/`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/checkout/)
  2. `svn checkout https://svn.example.com/svn/MyRepo/trunk/@REV`
- update your local working copy to REV revision:

  [`svn update --revision REV`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/update/)
- export (i.e. download) a file or a development branch in REV revision:

  1. [`svn export --revision REV https://svn.example.com/svn/MyRepo/trunk/`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/export/)
  2. `svn export https://svn.example.com/MyRepo/trunk/@REV`

You may notice that with `svn checkout` and `svn export` you can enter REV number as `--revision REV` argument and as trailing `@REV` after URL. The first one is called operative revision, and the second one is called peg revision. [Read SVNBook for more information about peg and operative revisions concept](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/pegrevs/).

Answer (score 9):

### svn checkout to revision where your repository is on another server

Use `svn log` command to find out which revisions are available:

```
svn log
```

Which prints:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r762 | machines | 2012-12-02 13:00:16 -0500 (Sun, 02 Dec 2012) | 2 lines

------------------------------------------------------------------------
r761 | machines | 2012-12-02 12:59:40 -0500 (Sun, 02 Dec 2012) | 2 lines
```

Note the number `r761`.  Here is the command description:

```
svn export http://url-to-your-file@761 /tmp/filename
```

I used this command specifically:

```
svn export svn+ssh://machines@mywebsite.com/home1/oct/calc/calcFeatures.m@761 calcFeatures.m
```

Which causes calcFeatures.m revision 761 to be checked out to the current directory.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the syntax for this is `/rev:<revisionNumber>`

Documentation for this can be found [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html)

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
TortoiseProc.exe /command:checkout /rev:1234
```

to get revision 1234.

I'm not 100% sure the `/rev` option is compatible with `checkout`, but I got the idea from some [TortoiseProc documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html).

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use svn directly:

```
svn checkout URL[@REV]... [PATH]
```

and

```
svn help co
```

gives you a little more help.

Comment: as far as what I see, i think an example can help.

do you include or not include the brackets? what about 3 periods? what about the space after the 3 periods? Which characters are literal, and which are placeholders, and which are added characters for the placeholders?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you can use the repository browser. Click the revision button at top-right and change it to the revision you want. Then right-click your file in the browser and use 'Copy to working copy...' but change the filename it will check out, to avoid a clash.

Comment: What repository browser?

Answer (score 0):

Go to folder and use the command:

```
svn co {url}
```

Comment: What is `co`? I feel like this answer needs some expansion/explanation

Comment: it's short for "checkout". You can use `svn checkout...` also