# How to check out a particular version of code from SVN?

Tags: svn

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Checkout a specific revision from Subversion from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429034)

How can I check out a particular version of code from SVN (Subversion)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What client are you using?

```
svn checkout svn://repository/path@123
```

or

```
svn checkout -r 123 url://repository/path
```

or

> `TortoiseProc.exe /command:checkout /rev:1234`

Comment: also works with existing checkout after the fact, using "svn update"; for reference, [svn update](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html): "if no revision is given, it brings your working copy up to date with the HEAD revision. Otherwise, it synchronizes the working copy to the revision given by the --revision (-r) option."; and see also how to [specify revisions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.revision) "You can provide revision numbers, keywords, or dates (in curly braces) as arguments to the revision option."

Answer (score 4):

```
svn update -r NBR
```

It might also work with `svn up`, depending of your version of Subversion.

Comment: assumes the source has already been checked out (see orig question); but otherwise, yes (see also my comment on the accepted answer). For no particular reason, I do prefer this way, probably only because I've internalized the git way of doing things (where git co {tag|branch} is done after a clone.)

Answer (score 2):

```
svn checkout URL[@REV]... [PATH]
```

Example for `rev 2004`:

```
svn checkout file:///tmp/repos/test@2004 mine
```

[Documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html).