# how can I download an svn from blender version 2.79b

Tags: svn, branch, git-branch, blender

I do not want the current version: this is part of my school learning, learn to download previous versions.
But I can not find blender svn 2.79b, there is no longer the document that had the link of this svn, and I do not know how to navigate in its repository SVN.

https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/

try to navigate here and find what I'm looking for but I do not know much about this topic and how to differentiate branches and versions

[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPFsZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

- https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/ shows you branches and tags.
- https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/tags/ shows you tags

There is no 2.79b, only 2.79a: https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/tags/blender-2.79a-release/

The "[Building Blender on Windows](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Windows)" has the commands for trunk, but in your case, you need to [checkout a specific revision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4744763/6309):

```
svn checkout -r 62253 https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/tags/blender-2.79a-release/lib/win64_vc14/
```

---

For 2.79b and later, you need to `git clone` the repository, not `svn checkout`.
See [`developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/), which has [the tag 2.79b](https://developer.blender.org/rBf4dc9f9d68bddaa206b692e1d077d1a1f2bb1528)

```
git clone git://git.blender.org/blender.git --branch v2.79b
```

Comment: in the direct download you find this tablet with the source code of blender 2.79b http://download.blender.org/source/blender-2.79b.tar.gz How can you assemble this as your repository?

Comment: blender.org home page https://www.blender.org/download/
under the download button there is a line of text with links, the last one says INFO, click on info and see the last option, SOURCE, there download this blender file 2.79b in tar.gz how do you install this as a master repository?

Comment: I can convert the previous comment into a question or it is ok here as a comment, enter this topic or it would be better to turn it into a separate question ?

Comment: @BlenderBlackened I have found the 2.79b tag and sources, this time in a Git repository. See my edited answer.