# Where can I find this jar: commons-csv 0.1-524170

Tags: java, csv, download

I'm working on a project which requires `commons-csv v0.1-524170`, I have a link of the site of commons-csv: http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/csv/ , but I can't find that version.

I need it with the exact version of `0.1-524170`, where can I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their site (http://commons.apache.org/csv/) says that they do not have releases yet and all ready available builds are nightly.  So it is not a good idea to depend on it unless you are willing to live on bleeding edge.

I suggest using some recent build and do integration tests.

If you DO need exactly that version you could checkout that revision from subversion and build it yourself:
svn checkout -r 524170 http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/csv/trunk commons-csv

Comment: Thanks, but when I checking out, there is an error: `checkout http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/csv/trunk -r 524170 --depth=infinity --force
    Bad URL passed to RA layer
svn: URL 'http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/csv/trunk' doesn't exist`. But if I check out the head, it will be OK.

Comment: I believe that revision switch should go before URL (as in my example). Or, alternatively use "@revision_number" notation as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429034/checkout-a-specific-revision-from-subversion-from-command-line

Comment: You are right, success now. The command in my first comment is generated by subclipse plugin of eclipse, seems not correct.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/csv/downloads.html) there are currently no official downloads, and will not be until CSV moves out of the Sandbox.

That doesn't stop you from retrieving the development snapshot revisions from Apache's Nexus repository:

- https://repository.apache.org/index.html#nexus-search;gav~org.apache.commons~commons-csv~~~
- https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/commons/commons-csv/1.0-SNAPSHOT/

If you just want a download URL that retrieves the latest snapshot revision:

- https://repository.apache.org/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=snapshots&g=org.apache.commons&a=commons-csv&v=1.0-SNAPSHOT&e=jar

In conclusion, no sign of a 0.1 revision... Looks like you'll have to build it from source if you really need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the same from [Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/csv).

Comment: Thanks, it's the same site. PS: it's better to post this answer as a comment.