# SVN (auto) update

Tags: svn

i am running a VisualSVN server on a Windows 2012 (R2) server. I have created a working copy of my repository on the same machine. I have also installed Tortoise SVN on this machine. I would like to SVN update this working copy following a schedule. I have created a .bat file doing the following:

```
CD C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\
START TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"D:\Files\SVN_WorkingCopy\ApplicationScripts\" /closeonend:0
```

When i execute this bat manually (via remote desktop), the contents of the working copy gets updated fine. When i integrate this bat file in a Windos scheduled task however, the task runs successfully but the working copy is not update.

Any ideas, why ?

Thanks!

...obviously if you have any ideas on how to get this task done in a different way, i'd appreciate any suggestions. I still would like to understand, whats causing the above problem though :)

Eventhough this question might be somewhat related to [Checkout a specific revision from Subversion from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429034/checkout-a-specific-revision-from-subversion-from-the-command-line/28502684#28502684), it is not an exact duplicate as the automation aspect in my question is not dealt with in the related post.

Comment: Is there any reason to use a GUI tool to update the working copy when you clearly won't be there to look at the screen or press buttons?

Comment: No, there isnt. But its the only thing that i was able to set up and that brought me closest to where i want to get. Can you suggest a different approach and how to do it ?

Comment: Read this post, please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28502684/761095

Comment: Thanks. When using the Subversion command line, I can do an update on my working copy. But how can i integrate this action in a scheduled task - or automate it another way ?

Comment: Open the file in the text editor you created it with, remove the `START TortoiseProc.exe` line and type `svn update "D:\Files\SVN_WorkingCopy\ApplicationScripts\"` instead.