# How to tortoiseSVN update after commit?

Tags: shell, svn, tortoisesvn

I want the web server file to be updated automatically when the SVN server commit.

my update code

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:update /path:"D:\WebSite\Agent" /closeonend:1
exit /b
```

It can be updated automatically every few seconds, but I want to update it only when a commitment occurs. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You should never use TortoiseProc.exe as a command-line Subversion client! TortoiseProc should be utilized only for automating TortoiseSVN's GUI. See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28502684/761095